# why Ethernet MTU size is 1500?

Tags: linux-networking, traceroute

Can somebody explain that why the Ethernet Maximum Transmission Unit was chosen to be 1500 bytes (why exactly 1500) ? It might have some historical reason.

Comment: While possibly interesting, this question is not on-topic for Serverfault. Please have a look at the [help].

Answer (score 5):

Setting an upper limit for packet size was done for two reasons:

- ensure reliable transmission of the data (longer data are more susceptible to being corrupted and their CRC have lower changes of detecting/correcting the corruption);
- ensure that all Ethernet-compliant device have at least a 1500 byte buffer to send/receive packets.

As you suggested, the 1500 bytes limit is mainly here for historical reasons; modern Ethernet networks can work quite happily with bigger frame sized. This is the precise reason why [Jumbo frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_Frames) are implemented on server grade or high-end consumer Ethernet card.

Answer (score 1):

Found this googling a bit:

> Ethernet frame has 8 byte preamble, 6 byte source and 6 byte
>   destination mac address, mac type of 2 bytes, and 4 bytes CRC.
>   Assuming the MTU payload to be 1500 the total number of bytes comes to
>   1500 + 8 + 6 + 6 + 2 + 4 = 1526 bytes. Now between each frame there is
>   a inter frame gap of 12 bytes which constitues 9.6micro seconds gap
>   between each frame. This is essential so that frames dont mix up. So
>   the total size of each frame going out of a host is 1538 bytes.
>
> So at 10 Mbps rate, the frame rate is 10 Mbps / 1538 bytes = 812.74
>   frames / second.
>
> Now we can find the throughput or efficiency of link, to transmit 1500
>   bytes of payload. by multiplying the frame rate with the number of
>   bytes of the payload.
>
> So efficiency = 812.74 * 1500 * 8 = 9752925.xxxxx bps which is 97.5
>   percent efficient ( comparing with 10 MBps)

Quite interesting and well explained.

[Source](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/9211546/why-mtu-size-1500)

Comment: Actually am unable to understand it.. Are u saying based on the maximum efficiency IEEE would have fixed the maximum and minimum value ?

Comment: It comes from the source I posted but looks like so. Anyways, after some more research and, as @shodanshok said, now it's here for historical reasons.